# Select rows based on number of duplicates, ordered alphabetically

Tags: sql, mysql, duplicates

I'm trying to select the x most "popular" records from a table where there are a number of duplicate entries.  I've got so far as returning records based on the count of the duplicate fields, but I also need them in alphabetical order.

For example:

```
SELECT country, COUNT(*) TotalCount 
FROM destinations
GROUP BY country
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 4
```

This would return records as:

> **country - TotalCount**
>   Mexico - 15
>   Cuba - 12
>   USA - 10
>   Australia - 5

How would I go about returning them ordered by country?  I've tried changing the ORDER BY to the country field, but that then ignores the popularity, returning records with any number of duplicates.

Would a select within a select be the answer/possible?

Comment: You should show the desired outcome. Aus, Cuba, Mex, USA...

Comment: That's exactly how I was trying to Stephanie :) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't mySQL just do this:

```
Select country
     , count(*)
  from theTable
 group by country
having count(*) > 1
 order by country
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT country, count 
FROM 
           (SELECT country, COUNT(*) as count 
            FROM ... 
             HAVING ...) as Dup 
ORDER BY
        country
```

Comment: Thanks however I couldn't get the above to work - it just returned a single record(?)